# characteristic function of Gaussian derivative density

Tags: characteristic-functions, density-function

I am trying to obtain the characteristic function of the Gaussian derivative density with $\mu = 0$:

$f'(x) = \frac{-2x}{4 \sigma^3 \sqrt{2\pi}} e^{\frac{-x^2}{2\sigma^2}}$

Anyone could help me?